# Data on banks’ leverage

Tags: data, leverage, banks, asset, capital-structure

Does someone know free resources to estimate the leverage of the banking and financial sector at an aggregate level? In particular I would be interested in something like [Federal Reserve’s Flow of Funds](http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/z1/Current/z1.pdf) for the following regions:

-Europe (Austria, Belgium, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Ireland, Italy, the Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, and the United Kingdom)

-Japan

-Asia Pacific (Australia, Hong Kong, New Zealand, and Singapore)

-North America (Canada, United States)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

High level [Flow of funds](http://www.boj.or.jp/en/statistics/sj/sjhiq.pdf) comparative analysis for the U.S., Japan, and Euro Area by the bank of Japan.

[Country level report from the ECB](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/reports.do?node=1000004042). It is an 800+ page report so the link may take time to load (alternatively go to ECB data warehouse/reports/Euro Area accounts).

[Canadian financial flow accounts](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/13-020-x/2012002/tab-eng.htm) data.